# REACT JS - Firestore: How to check documents to validate existing documents and avoid duplicate documents

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to validate if I already have add a book of the same name AND grade (course) I'm not 100% sure if && works as AND in REACT but I think it does cause didn't got any complaints in the code anyways moving on to the issue:

```
const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const docRef = db.collection('libros').doc();

        docRef.get().then((doc) => {

            if (doc.id.descripcion == descripcion && doc.id.grado == grado) 
            {
                window.alert("Book exist already")
            }
            else {

                docRef.set({
                    materia: materia,
                    descripcion: descripcion,
                    editorial: editorial,
                    grado: grado,
                    precio: precio,
                    id: docRef.id

            }).then((r) => {
                window.alert("Book added")
            })}
    })
}
```

This is the snip code of where I'm having the issue my idea is to loop through all the documents I have in that collection I'm not sure if i'm writing it correctly (clearly not cause is not working).

The idea is that Documents have a field called Description and course (descripcion and grado) and I want to compare the documents first to check if they have the same description and course, like they can have the same description but not the same grade or the same grade but not the same description

(which I think I have that logic correctly) :  `doc.id.descripcion == descripcion && doc.id.grado == grado`

But it doesn't seem to be even running through that code, any tips are welcome and from what I understand is suppose to loop and check every document.

Edit: Forgot to add how it looks in the firebase and the input
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never find any duplicates:

```
const docRef = db.collection('libros').doc();

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.id.descripcion == descripcion && doc.id.grado == grado) {
        window.alert("Book exist already")
    }
    ...
```

The reason for this is that the first line creates a reference to the new doc. The next line then tries to load that doc, which will never give you any data.

The `doc.id.descripcion` and`doc.id.grado` are also wrong, and should probably be `doc.data().descripcion` and`doc.data().grado`. But that doesn't matter too much, since you'll never get a document from `get()` anyway, since you're trying to load a document from a reference you just created and never wrote to.

---

To ensure something is unique in Firestore, use it as the ID of the documents. So if you want the book name and grade to be unique, create the document ID from the book name and grade, instead of asking Firestore to generate a unique ID for you:"

```
const docId = descripcion + grado;
const docRef = db.collection('libros').doc(docId);

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        window.alert("Book exist already")
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Quick question #1! 
Why does the + works  ?
Quick question #2!
So if I didn't use another variable in this case docId would this as well work ?
```doc.data().descripcion == descripcion && doc.data().descripcion == grado```

Comment: #1) We're just concatenating strings there. So we create a document ID by combining the two values that you want to be unique. #2 I'm not sure what you mean there. In my code that check is no longer needed, since we already use the values in the document ID, so if the `doc.exists` then a document with that name and grade already exist.

Comment: #2 I'm aware is no longer needed but just wanted to know if it would work anyways

Comment: It does fix the issue for sure if I assign an ID value and then check if that one already exist but is there a way to check the value/data inside the document ? like for example if I wanted to do a check by using the data in the document, does it makes sense what I'm trying to ask ?

Comment: If you *also* want to check the values in the document data, you can do that with `doc.data()`, so `doc.data().descripcion` and `doc.data().grado`.

Comment: Alright example if I have 2 different collections 1 student and 1 books and I want to make sure only books of that student course/grade shows up then I would have to do something like

```docBooks = db.collection('books').doc();``` and ```docStudent = db.collection('student').doc() ``` and then 
 ```if(docBooks.data().course == docStudent.data().course)``` ? (This is my last question sorry for mixing languages sometimes)

Comment: If you want to filter books that are read from the database (instead of ensuring uniqueness), you'd [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)